# Including NA Values in structable()

Tags: r, na, vcd

I would like to make a contingency table using the vcd package structable function. Two of my selected columns (`consent_a` and `consent_b`) has  NA values as well as factor (Yes, No) values, because each case can be consented for procedure a OR procedure b, but not both. For instance if a case is consented for procedure a, they are not asked for procedure b (and thus `consent_b` would be NA).  In the contingency table, I want to include all cases where factor is yes, no, and NA.

```r
library(vcd)

mydata <- data.frame(
  report_year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014),
  report_week = c(1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  consenta = c("Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "No"),
  consentb = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Yes", NA, NA, "Yes", NA, "No"))

epicurve <- as.data.frame(structable(proj11[, c("report_epiweek", "report_year", "consent_a", "consent_b")]))
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data.  It sounds as if you're confusing `NULL` with `NA` or possibly a string with the value "NULL".  These are not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I am mixing up NULL and NA. I have provided additional code above to reproduce my data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the `vcd` package but as far as I can see there's no inbuilt means for retaining `NA` values when working with contingency tables.  However, you can achieve the same flattened table while keeping `NA`s with the base `table()` function.

```
as.data.frame(with(mydata, table(report_week, report_year, consent_a, consent_b, useNA = "ifany")))
```

If the result of this isn't suitable for your next steps then you could just replace the `NA`s in your dataset with a symbolic value and continue to use the `vcd` package.